# Disable Vertical Scroll in niceScroll Js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, nicescroll

I need horizontal scroll only in this section and hide vertical scroll

I have tried everything like `overflow-x:hidden` in every thing but its not working.

```html
<html>
    
 <body>
 
  <div class="boxscroll do-nicescrol" style="height:200px;">
  <h1>All Complex Ecosystems Have Parasites</h1>
  <p><strong>All Complex Ecosystems Have Parasites</strong></p>
  <p><strong> Cory Doctorow</strong></p>
  <p><strong> doctorow@craphound.com</strong></p>
  <p><strong> For the O&#8217;Reilly Emerging Technology Conference</strong></p>
  <p><strong> San Diego, California</strong></p>
  <p><strong> 16 March 2005</strong></p>
  <p>&#8212;</p>
  <p>This text is dedicated to the public domain, using a Creative Commons public domain dedication:</p>
  <p>&gt; Copyright-Only Dedication (based on United States law) &gt; &gt; The person or persons who have associated their<br />
  work with this &gt; document (the &#8220;Dedicator&#8221;) hereby dedicate the entire copyright &gt; in the work of authorship<br />
  identified below (the &#8220;Work&#8221;) to the &gt; public domain. &gt; &gt; Dedicator makes this dedication for the<br />
  benefit of the public at &gt; large and to the detriment of Dedicator&#8217;s heirs and successors. &gt; Dedicator intends<br />
  this dedication to be an overt act of &gt; relinquishment in perpetuity of all present and future rights &gt; under<br />
  copyright law, whether vested or contingent, in the Work. &gt; Dedicator understands that such relinquishment of all<br />
  rights &gt; includes the relinquishment of all rights to enforce (by lawsuit &gt; or otherwise) those copyrights in<br />
  the Work. &gt; &gt; Dedicator recognizes that, once placed in the public domain, the &gt; Work may be freely reproduced,<br />
  distributed, transmitted, used, &gt; modified, built upon, or otherwise exploited by anyone for any &gt; purpose, commercial<br />
  or non-commercial, and in any way, including &gt; by methods that have not yet been invented or conceived.</p>
  <p>&#8212;</p>
  <p>AOL hates spam. AOL could eliminate nearly 100 percent of its subscribers&#8217; spam with one easy change: it could simply<br />
  shut off its internet gateway. Then, as of yore, the only email an AOL subscriber could receive would come from another<br />
  AOL subscriber. If an AOL subscriber sent a spam to another AOL subscriber and AOL found out about it, they could terminate<br />
  the spammer&#8217;s account. Spam costs AOL millions, and represents a substantial disincentive for AOL customers to remain<br />
  with the service, and yet AOL chooses to permit virtually anyone who can connect to the Internet, anywhere in the world,<br />
  to send email to its customers, with any software at all.</p>
  <p>[&#8230;]</p>
  <p>A free ebook from http://manybooks.net/</p>
  </div>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://nicescroll.areaaperta.com/wp-content/plugins/jnicescroll/js/jquery.nicescroll.min.js"></script>
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $(".do-nicescrol").niceScroll();
  });
 </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: @Justas see my answer

Comment: @Mirko Cianfarani thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51307189/nicescroll-js-how-to-disable-vertical-scrollbar answer worked in the past, I don't use this lib now.

Answer (score 3):

For remove the horizontal scroll of script ***Nicescroll*** you must insert this option `horizrailenabled:false`.

So the script for you case is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".do-nicescrol").niceScroll("{horizrailenabled:false}");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an option of **overflowx** inside nicescroll plugin which remains true by default. Hope, this option will solve your issue. You can check details in below image or at https://github.com/inuyaksa/jquery.nicescroll/blob/master/jquery.nicescroll.js
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
$("body").niceScroll({
    horizrailenabled:false,
});
```