# nicescroll.js - how to disable vertical scrollbar?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, nicescroll

I use [jquery-nicescroll](http://www.bestjquery.com/?2ueUbkNe):

```
$(this.refs.container).niceScroll({
  cursorcolor: '#f16221',
  cursorwidth: '14',
  cursorminheight: '64',
  scrollspeed: '50',
  autohidemode: 'false',
  overflowy: 'false'
})
```

Currently it has both scrollbars: vertical and horizontal. I need to hide/disable vertical scrollbar but haven't found a solution. I have tried adding `overflowy: 'false'` but it didn't work. There is `horizrailenabled: false` which works well but there is no option for vertical.

Similar question:
[Disable Vertical Scroll in niceScroll Js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46765858/disable-vertical-scroll-in-nicescroll-js)

How to hide vertical scrollbar using [nicescroll](https://github.com/inuyaksa/jquery.nicescroll/blob/master/jquery.nicescroll.js)?

Comment: Have you tried `overflowy: false`, i.e a boolean and not a string?

Comment: Yes, tried boolean false. I use it inside React component. Also tried 'hidden'

Comment: have you tried disabling vertical overflow on the element via css ?

Comment: I was able to do this with #ascrail2000 {
  display: none !important;
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to add the below jQuery code for a complete solution, to disable and hide the vertical scrollbar:

```
var nice = 
    $(this.refs.container).niceScroll({
        cursorcolor: '#f16221',
        cursorwidth: '14',
        cursorminheight: '64', 
        scrollspeed: '50',
        autohidemode: 'false',
        overflowy: 'false'
    });

var _super = nice.getContentSize;

nice.getContentSize = function () {
    var page = _super.call(nice);
    page.h = nice.win.height();
    return page;
}

$('.nicescroll-rails.nicescroll-rails-vr').remove();
```

(partially mentioned on https://code.google.com/archive/p/jquery-nicescroll/issues/27)